# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "AS"

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

getting error

```
Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.
SQL> show errors;
Errors for PROCEDURE CREATEBANKACCOUNT:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------
3/1      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "AS"


create or replace procedure 

CreateBankAccount(e1 varchar,e2 varchar,e3 varchar,e4 varchar,e5 varchar,e6 varchar);

as

begin

insert into accountDetails values(e1,e2,e3);

insert into personalDetails values(e4,e5,e6,e1);

end;

/
```

Comment: Also, please see "How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?" (http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 3):

You should not have a semicolon `;` after the closing `)` of the parameter list.

```
create or replace procedure CreateBankAccount(
  e1 varchar,
  e2 varchar,
  e3 varchar,
  e4 varchar,
  e5 varchar,
  e6 varchar)  /* No ; here! */
as
begin
  insert into accountDetails  values(e1,e2,e3   );
  insert into personalDetails values(e4,e5,e6,e1);
end;
/
```

Comment: nyffenegger it worked ,i also want to know that how to see the procedures stored;

Comment: @DebpratimGhosh You mean you want to see the text of the stored procedure? `select text from user_source where name = '....'`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolon after your first bracket:

```
create or replace procedure CreateBankAccount(e1 varchar,e2 varchar,e3 varchar,e4 varchar,e5 varchar,e6 varchar)
as
  begin
    insert into accountDetails values(e1,e2,e3);
    insert into personalDetails values(e4,e5,e6,e1);
end;
/
```